# red5 actionscript

Tags: java, actionscript, red5

How to get a parameter encode in the url ? 
for exemple, if we have an html file containning  : 
 
how to get the value of a from application.java class ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since Red5 is based on RTMP, there is no http request to get parameters from. Instead, you need to send the parameter from the client swf to Red5 over RTMP. Depending on what data you are passing you could either send this data as a connection parameter to the NetConnection or you could define a method on the Application class which the client will invoke on the NetConnection.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding but are you trying to access a parameter send in the RTMP uri? Such as "auth_token" in this URL: rtmp://localhost/myapp/foo?x=0&auth_token=aavsgwqh
If yes, then look at the tcUrl property of your connection parameters.